# Unable to display SVG image on screen ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to learn react js through a tutorial and in that I created a reusable component where info could be shown, but in that unable to display my svg image. It looks like this-

[image]

See how the image does not show and `alt` is shown.

To make this I made three files
1)`index.js` - which renders the reactJS

```
const InfoSection = ({
    lightBg,
    imgStart,
    topLine,
    lightText,
    headLine,
    description,
    buttonLabel,
    img,
    alt,
    id,
    darkText,
  }) => {
return (
        <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
            <InfoWrapper>
                <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
                    <Column1>
                    <TextWrapper>
                        <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                        <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headLine}</Heading>
                        <Subtitle darktext={darkText}>{description}</Subtitle>
                        <BtnWrap>
                            <Button to='home'>{buttonLabel}</Button>
                        </BtnWrap>
                    </TextWrapper>
                    </Column1>
                    <Column2>
                        <ImgWrap>
                            <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
                        </ImgWrap>
                    </Column2>
                </InfoRow>
            </InfoWrapper>
        </InfoContainer>
    )
}
```

2. `InfoElements` - consists of all the styled components and css, Pertaining to the issue, `ImgWrap` and `Img` are this,

```
export const ImgWrap = styled.div`
  max-width: 555px;
  height: 100%;
`;

export const Img = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
`;
```

3. `data.js` file- where I am passing my data

```
export const homeObjOne = {
    id: 'about',
    lightBg: false,
    lightText: true,
    lightTextDesc: true,
    topLine: 'About',
    headLine: 'headline',
    description:
      'description',
    buttonLabel: 'Get Started',
    imgStart: false,
    img: require('../../images/about.svg'),
    alt: 'alt line, if image does not show up',
    dark: false,
    primary: true,
    darkText: false
  };
```

I tried different ways of writing this line in the `data` file,

`img: require('../../images/about.svg')`

the path here is correct otherwise react would give an error. I used `require` here cause that's how it was done in the tutorial I am following.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the image to show up?

Comment: Hi, how are implemented Img component?

Comment: Have you tried adding an import to the top of the data file like this? `import logo from '../../images/about.svg';` and then setting the img key in your object to be logo

Comment: @FarhadKhan Yes, I did try that and it works but then it is not responsive enough and doesn't have the css properties of ```Img``` and ```imgWrap```

Comment: Take a look to Img component. I make example very similar of what you have and it worked https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-28jji9?file=src%2FApp.js. I am using img, not a wrapper component

Comment: @lissettdm You are right, it works for you but here I am unable to figure out the issue cause you put ```homeObjOne``` in the same file with render and I have just placed them in two different files. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that InfoSection are receiving img prop correctly?

Comment: @lissettdm I updated the ```index.js``` file to show how I am passing objects of ```homeObjOne```, please have a look.

Comment: I put everything in different files and it works the same way. Maybe the img property does not have the expected value. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-28jji9?file=src%2Findex.js. How are you calling < InfoSection img=??? />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224899/discussion-between-devang-mukherjee-and-lissettdm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on the same exercise and I got exactly the same error.

I did it in a different way, imported using     `import homeObjOneImg from "../../images/svg-3.svg";` and then set `img: homeObjOneImg`

```
import homeObjOneImg from "../../images/svg-3.svg";

export const homeObjOne = {
    id: 'about',
    lightBg: true,
    lightText: false,
    lightTextDesc: false,
    topLine: 'topLine',
    headLine: 'headLine',
    description: 'description',
    buttonLabel: 'buttonLabel',
    imgStart: false,
    img: homeObjOneImg,
    alt: 'alt',
    dark: false,
    primary: false,
    darkText: true
}
```